# How to catch SQLServer timeout exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, error-handling

I need to specifically catch SQL server timeout exceptions so that they can be handled differently.  I know I could catch the SqlException and then check if the message string Contains "Timeout" but was wondering if there is a better way to do it?

```
try
{
    //some code
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{

    if (ex.Message.Contains("Timeout"))
    {
         //handle timeout
    }
    else
    {
         throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for a ConnectionTimeout or a CommandTimeout, ie are you expecting the connection to fail or the executed command to fail?

Comment: I'm looking for a CommandTimeout, which is set to a default of 30 secs i think

Answer (score 187, accepted):

To check for a timeout, I believe you check the value of ex.Number. If it is -2, then you have a timeout situation.

-2 is the error code for timeout, returned from DBNETLIB, the MDAC driver for SQL Server. This can be seen by downloading [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/), and looking under System.Data.SqlClient.TdsEnums for TIMEOUT_EXPIRED.

Your code would read:

```
if (ex.Number == -2)
{
     //handle timeout
}
```

Code to demonstrate failure:

```
try
{
    SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(@"Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Data Source=YourServer,1433;Initial Catalog=YourDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
    sql.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = sql.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "DECLARE @i int WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 from sysobjects) BEGIN SELECT @i = 1 END";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // This line will timeout.

    cmd.Dispose();
    sql.Close();
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    if (ex.Number == -2) {
        Console.WriteLine ("Timeout occurred");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much what I'm doing at the moment, but it's not very elegant checking for -2

Comment: Download Red Gate's Reflector, and search for TIMEOUT_EXPIRED. It lives in System.Data.SqlClient.TdsEnums, and its value is -2. :o)

Comment: For those who do not have access to Reflector: [link](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/fx/src/Data/System/Data/SqlClient/TdsEnums@cs/1305376/TdsEnums@cs)

Comment: @brodie That's why you should make a constant for it and you can explain where the "magic" value came from in a comment on the constant.

Comment: The error numbers are documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-events-and-errors?view=sql-server-ver16  (it is -2 for execution timeout)

Comment: This demonstration code is a "very nice to have"!

Answer (score 27):

Updated for c# 6:

```
    try
    {
        // some code
    }
    catch (SqlException ex) when (ex.Number == -2)  // -2 is a sql timeout
    {
        // handle timeout
    }
```

Very simple and nice to look at!!

Comment: Thanks... I like your suggestion and use it.

Answer (score 24):

here: http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/DotNet/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.adonet/2006-10/msg00064.html

You can read also that *Thomas Weingartner* wrote:

> Timeout: SqlException.Number == -2 (This is an ADO.NET error code)
>   
> General Network Error: SqlException.Number == 11
>   
> Deadlock: SqlException.Number == 1205 (This is an SQL Server error code)

...

> We handle the "General Network Error" as a timeout exception too. It only occurs under rare circumstances e.g. when your update/insert/delete query will raise a long running trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Whats the value for the SqlException.ErrorCode property? Can you work with that?

When having timeouts, it may be worth checking the code for **-2146232060**.

I would set this up as a static const in your data code.

Comment: Looking at the docs for ErrorCode, it seems to me that it's reporting Interop-Level errors.  So it may be more on the level of COM errors or that a provider encountered an exception (generally) instead of a specific error relating to what you're doing.

Comment: @Eric is correct - that is an HRESULT code for the SqlException type, not for the source of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but when we have execute time out or command time out
The client sends an "ABORT" to SQL Server  then simply abandons the query processing. No transaction is rolled back, no locks are released. to solve this problem I Remove transaction in Stored-procedure and use SQL Transaction in my .Net Code To manage sqlException

Answer (score -2):

When a client sends ABORT, no transactions are rolled back. To avoid this behavior we have to use  SET_XACT_ABORT ON
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: It does not answer the question which is how to catch a command timeout in the c# code