# ADO/SQL Server: What is the error code for "timeout expired"?

Tags: sql-server, exception, timeout, ado

i'm trying to trap a "timeout expired" error from ADO.

When a timeout happens, ADO returns:

```
Number:      0x80040E31 (DB_E_ABORTLIMITREACHED in oledberr.h)
SQLState:    HYT00
NativeError: 0
```

The `NativeError` of zero makes sense, since the timeout is not a function of the database engine (i.e. SQL Server), but of ADO's internal timeout mechanism.

---

The `Number` (i.e. the COM hresult) looks useful, but the [definition of `DB_E_ABORTLIMITREACHED`](https://web.archive.org/web/20110921082938/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/joshpoley/archive/2008/01/04/errors-004-facility-itf.aspx) in [`oledberr.h`](http://examples.oreilly.com/9780735619616/cd_contents/devtools/include/oledberr.h) says:

> Execution stopped because a resource limit was reached. No results were returned.

This error could apply to things besides "*timeout expired*" (some potentially server-side), such as a governor that limits:

- CPU usage
- I/O reads/writes
- network bandwidth

and stops a query.

---

The final useful piece is `SQLState`, which is a database-independent error code system. Unfortunately the only [reference for SQLState error codes i can find](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/products?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/core/r0sttmsg.htm) have no mention of `HYT00`.

What to do?
What do do?

---

**Note:** i can't trust

```
0x80040E31 (DB_E_ABORTLIMITREACHED)
```

to mean "*timeout expired*", anymore than i could trust

```
0x80004005 (E_UNSPECIFIED_ERROR)
```

to mean "*Transaction was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim*".

---

My pseudo-question becomes: does anyone have documentation on what the SQLState "`HYT000`" means?

And my real question still remains: How can i specifically trap an ADO *timeout expired* exception thrown by ADO?

Gotta love the questions where the developer is trying to "*do the right thing*", but nobody knows **how** to do the right thing. Also gotta love how googling for `DB_E_ABORTLIMITREACHED` and this question is #9, with MSDN nowhere to be found.

### Update 3

From the [OLEdb ICommand.Execute reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms718095%28v=vs.85%29):

> DB_E_ABORTLIMITREACHED
>
> Execution has been aborted because a resource limit has been reached. For example, a query timed out. No results have been returned.

"*For example*", meaning not an exhaustive list.

---

### Update Three

Found it. Answer applied as answer.

Comment: Thanks for putting the effort into your question, including the links to all the reference information. It is helpful to others when doing similar research.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **can** safely use `HYT00` to mean **"Timeout expired"**. The following comes from Microsoft's [SQLSTATEs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms716412%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) reference. It mentions the `HYT00` SQLSTATE:

> The following SQLSTATEs indicate run-time errors or warnings and are good candidates on which to base programming logic. However, there is no guarantee that all drivers return them.
>
> 01004 (Data truncated)
>
> 01S02 (Option value changed)
>
> HY008 (Operation canceled)
>
> HYC00 (Optional feature not implemented)
>
> **HYT00 (Timeout expired)**

Which then links to [Appendix A: ODBC Error Codes of the ODBC Programmer's Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714687(v=vs.85).aspx), which documents the `SQLSTATE` values:

- `HYT00` Timeout expired, and interestingly also
- `HYT01` Connection timeout expired

So you can use HYT00 for "*Timeout expired*".

Answer (score 0):

Is it not just `-2` or is it too obvious?

You can generate this in both SSMS and from Ado.net and we use this to decide whether to retry.

[Old SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664/how-to-catch-sqlserver-timeout-exceptions) and a [link](http://blog.colinmackay.net/archive/2007/06/23/65.aspx) and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190181.aspx)

Comment: Where are you getting `-2` from? Nothing is returning -2. The HRESULT from the call to the ADO COM object is `0x80040E31`. After the failed HRESULT, the `Connection` object's `Errors` collection contains one error, with a `SQLState` of `"HYT00"` and `NativeError` of `0`.

Comment: We get -2 in several places in .net and SSMS. And so do lots of other people as per my links. What exactly are you doing at what level? you mention ADO, COM, ODBC and SQL Server

Comment: `hresult = connection.Execute(commandText, recordsAffected, adExecuteNoRecords);`  hresult will contain `0x80040E31`.  `connection.Errors` collection will contain members, with the `SQLState` being `"HYT00"`, and `NativeError` being 0. You're confusing `ADO` (native COM objects) with `ADO.net` (.NET managed objects)

Comment: In my case `-2` is not obvious at all. Not only do i not have -2 returned to me, but it seems no more correct that -42 (which i also don't receive)