# Filtering SqlServer Command Timeout Exception for ExecReader

Tags: c#, ado.net

How do get the specific exception that has caused a sql server command to happen using the SqlException object that I have caught.  I want to know when a Command timeout has occured, i.e.

```
try
{
    // database ExecReader call
}
catch (SqlException sqlEx)
{
    // what can I test here to find if this is a command timeout exception
}
```

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

Can I test sqlEx.Number or sqlEx.ErrorCode for the command timeout.  Is there a list of codes (for sqlEx.Number) and there corresponding meanings, I have googled but can't seem to find one and do the codes change depending on the version of sql server that I am using?

Thanks for any help,
Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried having a look here: [How to catch SQLServer timeout exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664/how-to-catch-sqlserver-timeout-exceptions) ?