# Catching a WCF Timeout Exception

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service that invokes a potentially long running DB procedure.  In the event that this causes a timeout in WCF, I want to handle this gracefully in the client.

Here is the code that I'm using the call the WCF service:

```
async Task<int> RunWCFServiceCall()
{
    try
    {
        int returnVal = await Task.Run<int>(() => CallService());

        return returnVal;
    }
    catch (FaultException ex)
    {
        if (ex.InnerException.GetType().Equals(typeof(TimeoutException)))
        {
            return 0;
        }
```

The code above catches the exception as a `FaultException`, but fails the inner exception check.  The reason being that `InnerException` is null; however, the exception message is:

```
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
```

My question is: how can I trap this error, specifically, without resorting to a messy construct of checking the exception message string?

Comment: Is the WCF Service something you have control over (i.e. can you change how the FaultException is raised?)

Comment: I have control over the service, although as it's a timeout, I don't really have control over that

Comment: See here for checking timeout exception http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664/how-to-catch-sqlserver-timeout-exceptions

Comment: As I'm catching a WCF error, it comes through as a FaultException - which doesn't have Number

Comment: I ended up using the magic number plus the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, WCF will be hiding the actual exception details, in much the same way that a production webserver won't display an error message.  You need to control the way the error is raised.

You can trap the exception in your service and raise it yourself as a FaultException with a specific FaultReason or FaultCode, or you can include the exception in your WCF contract.