# How to tell if ADODB CommandTimeout is reached?

Tags: sql, vba, ado

I have some VBA that queries a SQL database using ADODB. Currently I have the CommandTimeout set to 30 seconds. If nothing is returned, that can either be because no such record exists in the SQL database, or because the timeout was reached. I would like to be able to distinguish these two cases and display a warning when the timeout is reached. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: If the timeout is reached an error is thrown so its not a problem.

Comment: I think you prob want to investigate why you are getting a timeout in the first place

Comment: @Charlieface Well that's easy, I'm querying a giant database and don't want users to have to wait longer than 30 seconds for the query to run. I don't have any control over the structure of the database I'm querying, only the VBA.

Comment: I see. Still, giant databases can be queried in milliseconds with the correct indexes, so if you have permission to create indexes then there is plenty scope to speed up queries massively

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the authority to change the query either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to catch SQLServer timeout exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664/how-to-catch-sqlserver-timeout-exceptions)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly read this: [ADO Event Instantiation: Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/data/ado-event-instantiation-visual-basic?view=sql-server-ver15)

Check [EventStatusEnum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/eventstatusenum?view=sql-server-ver15) for adStatusOK - which should not be set in case TimeOut.

You could also catch up "InfoMessage"
[InfoMessage Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/infomessage-event-ado?view=sql-server-ver15) to see information like in SSMS when you run query.

Comment: Is it duplicated [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664/how-to-catch-sqlserver-timeout-exceptions) ? There was solution to NET but you are using VBA.